# Database table normalization (Many relations)

Tags: database, database-design, optimization, query-optimization

I have the following tables :

**Items { item_id, item_name, item_price,......}**
**Divisions { division_id, division_name, division_address,.......}**
**Warehouses { warehouse_id, warehouse_name,........}**
**WarehousePartitions { partition_id, partition_name,........}**
**WarehouseRacks { rack_id, rack_name,.......}**

Now, in order to track an item's location, I have the following table (a relation).

**itemLocation { item_id, division_id, warehouse_id, partition_id, rack_id, floor_number}**

It accurately tracks an item's location, but in order to get an items location info, I have to join five tables which can cause performance issues.

Also, the table doesn't have any Primary Key if we do not take the entire fields. Will this cause any issues ? and Is there a better way to accomplish this ?

Thanks.

Comment: It would help if you would name the DBMS you are using, and the approximate size of your tables (in rows).  A five way join is often done without major slowdown.

Comment: Currently, its MySQL, but I am migrating it to PostgreSQL soon.

Table sizes can be like Items = 10,000 - 100,000, Divisions < 100, Warehouses < 500, WarehousePartitions < 100, WarehouseRacks < 300.

Answer (score 2):

Think in terms of relationships, since you're putting information in a relational database.

Here are my relationship guesses.  Feel free to correct them.

- A Division has one or more Warehouses.
- A Warehouse has one or more Warehouse partitions.
- A Warehouse partition has one or more Warehouse Racks.
- A Warehouse rack has one or more items.

.

- An item is located in a Warehouse rack.
- A Warehouse rack is located in a Warehouse partition.
- A Warehouse partition is located in a Warehouse.
- A Warehouse is located in a Division.

I hope this helps with your database design.

Edited to add: I'll lay out the indexes for the tables.  You should be able to create the rest of the columns.

```
Division
--------
Division ID
...

Warehouse
---------
Warehouse ID
Division ID
...

Warehouse Partition
-------------------
Warehouse Partition ID
Warehouse ID
...

Warehouse Rack
--------------
Warehouse Rack ID
Warehouse Partition ID
...

Item
----
Item ID
Warehouse Rack ID
Item Type ID
...

Item Type
---------
Item Type ID
Item name
Item Price
```

Each table has a primary ID blind key, probably an auto incrementing integer or an auto incrementing long.

All of the tables except Division have a foreign key that points back to the parent table.

A row in the Item table represents one item.  One item can only be in one Warehouse Rack.

Modern relational databases should have no performance problems joining five tables.  I've seen 30 table joins.

Build your system, and solve the actual performance problems that come up, rather than spending any time worrying about hypothetical performance problems.

Comment: Yes except that an item is located in a Warehouse's rack's floor (say, there are ten floors to the rack and an item could be in one or more floors of the same or different rack). Thats what I use the "floor_number" in the itemLocation table for.

In this case, ItemLocation table works fine (tracks everything properly). But I am just suspicious that whether or not there will be any performance issues joining all these five tables.

Also, in such a case what a table structure would you suggest ?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm considering an item as an item, quantity 1.  You're trying to group all of the items in one row, which isn't going to work well for the reasons your gave.  Yes, my item table will have vastly more rows.

Comment: for your ease, I have drawn a picture. Please see it here : http://imagebin.org/246944 
Also, let me please know whats your best suggestion based on that. FYI, there will be one ore more such "pictures"(warehouses) to a division of the company. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As Gilbert Le Blanc writes, you probably don't need to join to five tables - you may only need to join to "WarehouseRacks".

However, you write that you need to "keep track of" - this suggests that there's a time aspect involved.

That gives you the following schema:

```
Items { item_id, item_name, item_price,......}
Divisions { division_id, division_name, division_address,.......}
Warehouses { warehouse_id, division_id, warehouse_name,........}
WarehousePartitions { partition_id, warehouse_id partition_name,........}
WarehouseRacks { rack_id, partition_id, rack_name,.......} 
ItemLocation (rack_id, item_id, entry_time, quantity, floor_number)
```

In ItemLocation, all 3 columns are part of a composite primary key - you're effectively saying "there can only be one instance of an item in a given place at any one time".

You still have to join to five tables to retrieve an item ID (at least if you want the addresses and names and such). Assuming you have modern hardware and database software, this should be fine - uUnless you're working with huge amounts of data, a 5-way join on a foreign/primary key relationship is unlikely to cause performance issues. Given the quantities you mention in the comment, and the fact you'll be running this on MySQL, I don't think you need to worry about the number of joins.

The benefit of this model is that you simply cannot insert invalid data into the item location table - you can't say that the item is in a rack which doesn't exist in the partition, or a warehouse that doesn't exist in the division; if a warehouse changes division, you don't have to update all the item_location records.

I've created a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2148a/1) to show how it might work.

The "item_location" table is the biggest concern in this - you have to choose whether to store a snapshot (which is what this design does), or a transaction table. With "snapshot" views, your code always updates the "quantity" column, effectively saying "as of entry_time, there are x items in this floor in this rack".

The "transaction" model allows you to insert multiple records - typically positive quantities when adding items, and negative quantities when removing them. The items in that location at any point in time are the SUM of those quantities up to the desired time.

Comment: No Neville, "an item can be in multiple places at a given time". For eg: there could be 10 Intel CPUs in a Rack of Warehouse X of Division Y. And there could be another, say 20, Intel CPUs in a rack of Warehouse P of Division Q.

Comment: Please see a structure of a warehouse here : http://imagebin.org/246944 and let me know your suggestions.